# OptaPlanner: How to add a planning entity with ProblemFactChange

Tags: optaplanner

I have a long running solver that I wish to periodically update with new planning entities (incoming orders).  Below is the sequence in the ProblemFactChange that I have pieced together.  Is this the correct sequence? I could not find an example for this.

```
solution = scoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();
scoreDirector.beforeEntityAdded(order);
solution.getOrderList().add(order);
scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners();
scoreDirector.afterEntityAdded(order);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see also [the new task assigning example which does that](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/taskassigning/swingui/TaskAssigningPanel.java#L204).