# OptaPlanner: how to change an entity with ProblemFactChange

Tags: optaplanner

Similar to [OptaPlanner: How to add a planning entity with ProblemFactChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055070/optaplanner-how-to-add-a-planning-entity-with-problemfactchange)

I have a long running solver where the contents of an order may change during solving.  How do I introduce that change to the solver using a ProblemFactChange?  ScoreDirectory has beforeEntityAdded/afterEntityAdded and beforeEntityRemoved/afterEntityRemoved methods, but I don't see any for changing an existing entity.

Should I just queue a remove followed by an add?

Answer (score 0):

No need to remove + add, as that's a (insignificant?) perf loss.

Instead, just call before/afterProblemFactChanged once for all non planning variable field changed and before/afterVariablechanged for every genuine/shadow variable field changed.